# custom domain changing url back to heroku domain

Tags: heroku, dns, hosting, cname

I just set up a Ghost blog on heroku. under settings I get https://myghostblog.herokuapp.com/ as the domain. I wanted to connect a custom sub-domain, thus I added the custom sub-domain www.blog.customdomain.com in heroku and added the heroku given DNS target to CNAME of my google domain. yet When i visit www.blog.customdomain.com the browser changes the address in the browser to the heroku app domain https://myghostblog.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Heroku support is great for domain configuration issues. Just open a ticket and they'll help you out.

Answer (score 1):

My HEROKU_URL was set to https://myghostblog.herokuapp.com/ changing it to http://blog.customdomain.com, and then clearing cache or trying in private tab did the trick.